# 3 Sets of Wires Confusion

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

There was an old junction box in our family room with a metal cover over it. It looks like there was probably a wall sconce there at one point and I thought I’d install a new one. However, the wires inside are really confusing and I’m not sure how to proceed. There are two white wires capped together, two black wires and a white wire covered in black sharpie capped together, and a single black wire with black tape on it capped by itself. I am guessing this is some sort of 3 way switch wiring, but I’m not sure what to connect with the wires on the light fixture. Any ideas? See my picture for reference. Thank you[image]

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a classic switch loop with the white wire marked black. With your power turned off, connect your white fixture wire to the group of white wires in the box. Connect your black fixture wire to the single black wire in the box. The box doesn't appear to be grounded so just leave the copper wire from the fixture, if there is one, unhooked and tucked into the box.

Comment: Thank you! I’ve never seen this before and was starting to scare myself!